# Why is map reduce job poinitng to localhost:8080?

Tags: hadoop, java-8, mapreduce, bigdata

I am working with Map Reduce job and executing it using ToolRunner's run method.
Here is my code:

```
public class MaxTemperature extends Configured implements Tool {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
      int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperature(), args);
      System.exit(exitCode);
  }

  @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
              System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
              System.exit(-1);
            }
        System.out.println("Starting job");
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
        job.setJobName("Max temperature");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;

        if(job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was successful");
        } else if(!job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was not successful");           
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

The job executed well as expected. But when i looked into the logs which displays the information abou the job tracking, I found that the Map reduce is pointing to localhost:8080 for the tracking of the job.

Here is the snapshot of logs:

```
20521 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - number of splits:1
20670 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Submitting tokens for job: job_local1454583076_0001
20713 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - file:/tmp/hadoop-KV/mapred/staging/KV1454583076/.staging/job_local1454583076_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
20716 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - file:/tmp/hadoop-KV/mapred/staging/KV1454583076/.staging/job_local1454583076_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
20818 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - file:/tmp/hadoop-KV/mapred/local/localRunner/KV/job_local1454583076_0001/job_local1454583076_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
20820 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - file:/tmp/hadoop-KV/mapred/local/localRunner/KV/job_local1454583076_0001/job_local1454583076_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
**20826 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/**
20827 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Running job: job_local1454583076_0001
20829 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - OutputCommitter set in config null
```

So my question is why is map reduce pointing to localhost:8080

> The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/

There is no configuration file or properties file where i manually set this. Also, is it possible that i can change it to some other port? If yes, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you running this in local mode or on a cluster?

Comment: It must be `localhost:8088`, the default port for ApplicationMaster Web UI.

Comment: Its in local mode and its 8080 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to change the default configuration and create a Configuration object and set the properties to this configuration object and then create a Job object using this Configuration as follows:

```
    Configuration configuration  = getConf();

    //configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.**.***.2**");
    //configuration.set("mapred.job.tracker", "jobtracker:jtPort");
    configuration.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "localhost:54311");
    configuration.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
    configuration.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "127.0.0.1:8032");

    //configuration.set("yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address", "127.0.0.1:8032");

    //Initialize the Hadoop job and set the jar as well as the name of the Job
    Job job = new Job(configuration);
```

Answer (score 1):

So the ports are configured in yarn-site.xml : [yarn-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Check : yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address